# Passing a value from a MySql dropdown to the other without posting on the Db-php

Tags: php, mysql, nested, dropdown

I have three tables: contacts, companies and contact-companies. I would like that when a user select from a dropdown list a particular company, in the following dropdown list, he could see only the contacts in the company previously selected. I tried to use a global function but with VERY limited success.
I would like to avoid posting the result of the first query result if possible.

```
<p>Company <span>*</span></p>
  <span class="icon-case"><i class="fa fa-comments-o"></i></span>
  <select name="company">';
    echo '<option value=""></option>;'

        <?php

        $query="SELECT `name` FROM `companies` ORDER BY `name`ASC";
        $result=mysqli_query($connection,$query) or die ("Query to get data from sector table failed: ".mysql_error());

global $company_id;

        while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $company_id=$row["company_id"];


        $company_name=$row["name"];
        echo "<option value=\"$company_id\">
         $company_name
         </option>";
        }

        ?>

    </select>

  </div>  


       <p>Contact in Company <span>*</span></p>
  <span class="icon-case"><i class="fa fa-comments-o"></i></span>
  <select name="contact">';
    echo '<option value=""></option>;'

        <?php
        global $company_id;

        $query="SELECT * FROM `contact_company` WHERE 

`company_id=$company_id;";

        $result=mysqli_query($connection,$query) or die ("Query to get data from sector table failed: ".mysql_error());

        while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $company_id=$row["company_id"];
        $contact_id=$row["contact_id"];
        echo "<option value=\"$company_id\">
         $contact_id
         </option>";
        }

        ?>

    </select>

  </div>
```

Any suggestion?
Regards
Tommaso

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are missing something. here is the snippet

```
<?php 

$connection = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS,DATABASE); if (mysqli_connect_errno()) echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error(); 

echo '<p>Company <span>*</span></p>
  <span class="icon-case"><i class="fa fa-comments-o"></i></span>
  <select name="company" id="company">';

    echo '<option value="">Please select</option>';

      $query="SELECT name,company_id FROM `companies` ORDER BY `name`ASC";
                $result=mysqli_query($connection,$query) or die ("Query to get data from sector table failed: ".mysql_error());



        while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $company_id=$row["company_id"];


        $company_name=$row["name"];
        echo "<option value=".$company_id.">".$company_name."   </option>";
        }



    echo '</select>

  </div>  

  <p>Contact in Company <span>*</span></p>
  <span class="icon-case"><i class="fa fa-comments-o"></i></span>
  <select name="contact" id="contact">';
    <option value=""> Please select</option>
    </select>';

?>

<script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"   integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#company').on('change',function(){
        var companyid = $(this).val();
        alert('hello');
        if(companyid){
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'ajaxData.php',
                data:'id='+companyid,
                success:function(html){
                    $('#contact').append(html);

                }
            }); 
        }
    });
});

</script>
```

Ajaxdata.php

```
<?php /* Connect to MySQL and select the database. */ 
$connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '','demo'); if (mysqli_connect_errno()) echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
?>
<?php 
$company_id=$_POST['id'];
echo $query="SELECT * FROM `contact` WHERE company_id='".$company_id."'";

 $result=mysqli_query($connection,$query) or die ("Query to get data from sector table failed: ".mysqli_connect_error());

 while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $company_id=$row["company_id"];
        $contact_id=$row["contact_id"];
        echo "<option value=\"$company_id\"> $contact_id</option>";
        }
```

Comment: @Vlshal thank you very much for your response, actually in my php file I was not connecting to the db. However, I still cannot manage to make it work and in your code, there must be some missing bit due to the indentation.

Comment: Actually before have the nested query to work I would like to see the ajax working. I can make it work I hardcode the options but not If I populate the dropdown from MySql. Can you please suggest me a snippet that just return the selection on the html?

Comment: My php file luooks like this: <?php 
  include "../inc/dbinfo.inc"; 
  require_once("../html/Header.php"); /*in the Header I have the JQuery */

?>
<style>
<?php 
  include '../html/css/Formcss.css'; ?>
</style>

<?php

  /* Connect to MySQL and select the database. */
  $connection = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD);

  if (mysqli_connect_errno()) echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();

  $database = mysqli_select_db($connection, DB_DATABASE);

  ?>

<?php 
$output=$_POST["allbooks"];
echo $output;
?>

Comment: Great to hear it works.Please accept it as answer if it helps

Answer (score 1):

I will Recommend to use use ajax to get desired contacts. Below is the snippet that can be helpful

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#company').on('change',function(){
        var companyid = $(this).val();
        if(companyid){
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'ajaxData.php',
                data:'id='+companyid,
                success:function(html){
                    $('#conatct').html(html);

                }
            }); 
        }
    });
});
```

On change of company, we can make ajax call.Below are the parameters for Ajax

1. Type: should be POST or GET
2. Url: php file from data will be fetched based on the seelct company
3. Data: Selected company
4. Sucess: where to display fetched data.

As company is is provided in post format in php file
$company_id=$_POST['id'];
based on this we can fetch the data from database.

Comment: thank you very much for your reply. Unfortunately I don't seem to make it work. I created a div called "show" and I slightly modified the script as follows:

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#company').on('change',function(){
        var companyid = $(this).val();
        if(companyid){
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'Actions_company.php',
                data:'id='+companyid,
                success:function(html){
                    $('#show').html(html);

                }
            }); 
        }
    });
});
</script>

Comment: the Actions_company.php file looks like this:   <?php

  /* Connect to MySQL and select the database. */
  $connection = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD);

  if (mysqli_connect_errno()) echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();

  $database = mysqli_select_db($connection, DB_DATABASE);

 $company_id=$_POST['company_id'];

  ?>    I do not see any output whatsoever, can you please help?

Comment: Please share your query/script. Ideally, it should be something like: select field_name from table where company_id=$company_id.It will give you desired results.With this you can creat drop down options with contact values and pass it to #show.Hope it helps

Comment: Here is the script on the php file, I added some debugging lines. The behaviour is really strange if I add <?php on top it doesnt work, If I remove it, it displays on the webpage the content of the php script

<?php
$output = ($_POST['allbooks']);
echo $output;
ini_set('display_errors', 1); 
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
?>